# Change language being used in Angular-ui Calendar

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, fullcalendar

I am using the [Angular-UI calendar](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar) to display some events.

i want to convert the language from english to french eg: January to Janvier

please help me

Comment: What is the problem,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the lang option in the [fullCalendar Docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/lang/)

```
<script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/lang-all.js'></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            lang: 'fr'
        });

    });

</script>
```

Above is the regular js solution. Looking through the Angular-UI calendar docs, I reckon your solution would be similar but something like:

```
myAppModule.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    /* config object */
    $scope.uiConfig = {
      calendar:{
        lang: 'fr'
      }
    };
});
```